# Pandas - Change AM/PM format to 24h

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have some time input in the format of `'10:23:34 PM'` in string and I'd like to convert it to a datetime looking like `'22:23:45'`. I'm using

```
datetime = posts['time'].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%I:%M:%S %p').strftime('%I:%M:%S'))
```

However, this seems to disregard the AM/PM markers, and all the info comes out as if the time was in the AM, ergo for the `'10:23:34 PM'` input I get `'10:23:34'` as output, but it should be `'22:23:45'`. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You want `%H` not `%I`:

```
In [44]:
d='10:23:34 PM'
pd.to_datetime(d).strftime('%H:%M:%S')

Out[44]:
'22:23:34'
```

`%I` returns the 12-hour clock format, you want `%H` to return the 24-hour format, see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

I think you can do this without using `apply` here:

```
datetime = pd.to_datetime(posts['time']).dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

Note this gives you strings rather than a datetime